# Determine All Functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

> Determine All Functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that have the
>   following properties:
>
> a) $ f $ is three times differentiable with $ f '' '(x) \geq 0 $, for
>   all $ x \in [0,1] $
>
> b) $ f '$ is increasing and strictly positive:
>
> c) $ f '(1) (2f (1) -f (0) -f' (1)) \int ^ 1_0 \frac {dx} {(f '(x)) ^
>  2} = 1 $

$$\frac{-\pi}{2}<x < \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$0 < \frac{\pi}{2}+x < \pi$$
$$0 < \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+x}{\pi}<1$$

So the function $$f (x) = tan (\frac {x} {\pi}) + \frac {1} {2}$$ This is a possible function.

Finding them all is hard

I think that can prove that cardinality in $ (0,1) $ is equal to cardinality in reais by proving that there is a bijective function that satisfies, But I could not

Comment: There seems to be plenty of interesting geometry to study by applying from these hypotheses. Have you explored those directions? For example, what else occurred to you when you applied a) to conclude that the graph of $f'(x)$ is concave upward, and then combined that with b) and then c)?

Comment: @LeeMosher I found something about, what do you think? (PAG 6) http://www.mathproblems-ks.org/?wpfb_dl=7